# How to show, edit user profile when logged in with php

Tags: php, mysqli

Please i want logged in user to be able to view and edit their previous details in a mysql database..here is my code so far

```
<?php session_start(); include 'dpconfig.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) 
{
      echo $_SESSION['uid'];
}
else 
{
      echo "You are not Logged In!";  header("Location: header.php"); 
} 

$n = mysqli_query($conn,"Select * from user");
$run = mysqli_query($conn,"Select * from user"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($run, MYSQLI_BOTH); 
{
    $showid = $row[0]; 
    $showfirst = $row[1]; 
    $showlast = $row[2]; 
    $showuid = $row[3]; 
    echo $showid; 
    echo $showfirst;
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but that code does not look like you have any idea what you are doing. I would recommend that you first go through some "getting started" tutorials. There is little sense in us copying all that to you here. Your questions is far too broad and so vague that it cannot be answered.

Comment: Your code is just too messy. i found you load user info. May the next step is showing a form to user to populate new values and you manage the form.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do when your user have log in you then need to have links in the dashboard to profile page then you need to have a query string in your link

eg

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include 'dpconfig.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) 
{
      echo $_SESSION['uid'];

      echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=".$_SESSION['uid']."&action=view\">View Profile<a/>";
      echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=".$_SESSION['uid']."&action=edit\">Edit Profile</a>";
}else{


    // not allowed redirect
}
?>
```

The above code is just a basic dashboard after the user have loggedin, we display to links to profile.php with two query string parameters, namely id we will use this to identify the current user, and action, this one will help us to know what action the user is doing(viewing/editing) their profile

Then once they on any of the link, it will go to the profile.php page with url params. then we use GET method to do our proccessing

Read about Get method [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

profile.php

```
<?php
    session_start();

  include 'dpconfig.php';

    if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['action'])){

        if($_GET['action'] === "view"){


            // show user profile
        }


        if(isset($_GET['action']) ==="edit"):?>

        show html form with profile info to edit then process

        <?php

        endif;

    }else{

        // not allowed do something
    }




?>
```

Hope this will atleast point you to the correct direction.